# Laptop screen turns black when I unplug from charger

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, battery, power

My laptop is Asus A555LF. Its over 5 years old. For the later part of those years, every time the laptop goes in battery mode, or when I unplug the charger form the laptop, the screen gones blank. The laptop has poor power back up since the battery is at the end of its life cycle but even so when I unplug, the laptop is actually running and the screen is slightly lit (you have to see it at night with no lights to notice this not 100% blank or switched off ) . I tried dual booting other OS like different version of window and even Ubuntu but its the same issue.

Could you please tell me how I can diagnose this problem? is it issues with the mouther board? the monitor or actually the battery? (though I doubt it since practically nothing changed for the laptop other than the screen )
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to diagnose this problem would be to insert a new battery into your laptop, charge it and pull the power plug.

Any other efforts to diagnose will be much more expensive than that.

I expect your battery to be the culprit anyway.
A used battery will show effects of fast voltage reduction and high internal resistance. Both effects combined will yield a low battery voltage when there is a load for the battery.

Below a certain battery voltage either the firmware or the operation system takes protective measures but a circuit failing to work due to extreme low voltage could be a possibility for your darkening screen as well.